# How to schedule plain java programs using oozie without map/reduce or hadoop?

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, oozie

Is oozie can be installed and running without Hadoop. I refer oozie materials where hadoop is needed.

Let's say i have 2 plain Java applications.Now I want to chain these 2 Java applications in a oozie workflow and want to produce the final JSON output from the 2nd Java code. I don't want to code these 2 Java applications in Map/reduce program. They should be plain Java code.

Please suggest.

Comment: you could run the java program using the java action in oozie mentioning the main class to be invoked , runtime arguments etc.

Comment: So, do I need to install hadoop too ?

Comment: The oozie installation uses hadoop libs , and hadoop realted properties in the oozie-site.xml. I havent tried installing oozie without hadoop, but you could give a try.

Comment: Have you succeededM Or its not possible?